# In SuperH assembly, how close do constants have to be to the move operations that use them?

Tags: assembly, gnu-assembler, superh

It seems to be possible to move the value of a constant into a register directly in SuperH assembly, without the explicit use of an address:

```
my_subroutine:
    mov.w my_const, r1

    <code omitted for brevity>

    rts
    nop

my_const: .word 0x7070
```

However, if I try it like this:

```
my_const: .word 0x7070

my_subroutine:
    mov.w my_const, r1

    <code omitted for brevity>

    rts
    nop
```

I get the error: `Error: pcrel too far`.

I'm guessing there is some sort of small address offset that is used to access `my_const` that fits nicely into the opcode, and if this offset is too large (or if it's negative) then I will run into this pcrel error.

My questions are:

1. Assuming my understanding of how this works is correct, how large can this offset be? 8 bits I think? I can see several move operations described in the sh-1/sh-2/sh-dsp manual that involve "disp" (I'm guessing this is the offset I'm thinking about) but I'm a little confused as to which move applies here. Each use of "disp" (in the context of a move operation in the manual) also includes the use of `@`, which I'm not using here. Looking for a little more clarity on this.
2. What is the best coding practice here? I have been making one file for each subroutine so far (and including each of these files in a footer) and it would be nice to have constants associated with the subroutine defined immediately after the implementation of that subroutine so I can have all relevant information in one file. However, I'm not sure if it's a good idea to have these constants sort of "sprinkled" throughout my code. Any info here would be helpful.
3. Is it possible to access variables in the same way? Right now I have a .data section at the end of my code (in a footer) for a few variables I am using in my various subroutines. It would be nice to be able to include these in the same file as the subroutine, same as the constants, but I'm not sure I can or should interleave .text and .data sections. (Assuming .include just inserts the contents of the file at the relevant location)
4. Somewhat related: it seems like normally in assembly you have sections .text for code, .bss for variables, and .data for constants. It's hard to find examples of SuperH assembly in gnu assembler syntax, but from experimentation I have found that I can read and write from variables declared in a .data section (and also initialize them), and I can read but not write to variables declared in a .text section, so I'm just assuming I can use this section for constants. I tried to declare a .bss section but I got the error "unknown pseudo-op", so perhaps this arch doesn't support it? Or I'm declaring it wrong?

Comment: 32-bit ARM typically does the same thing, using "literal pools" in gaps between functions in the `.text` section, addressed with a PC-relative addressing mode that can't reach far enough to reliably reach the `.rodata` or `.data` sections in a non-tiny executable.  ARM assemblers can create literal pools automatically when you do stuff like `ldr r0, =0x12345678` or `=symbol`.  (The `=` being the indicator that it's a pseudo-instruction to materialize that constant or symbol address in a register, rather than a load from there.)  I don't know anything about Super-H, though, though.

Comment: I assume the instruction that gets used under the hood here is `MOV.W @(disp, PC), Rn`, which means that _"the 8-bit displacement is zero-extended and doubled. Consequently, the relative interval from the table is up to PC + 510 bytes"_ (from _SuperH RISC Engine SH-1/SH-2 Programming Manual_).

Comment: Just naming a label `my_const` doesn't inform on the section it is in, so it could be a variable.  Have you considered using `equ` or similar?